# Force carriage returns in IEx Ports' stderr?

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-iex

If I open a Port in IEx for a script that prints anything to stderr, none of the output is printed with carriage returns. How can I fix this? I am running external software whose output I cannot control, so I can't just add the returns manually.

#### Example

In `/tmp/run.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
>&2 echo -e "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4"
```

In an IEx shell

```
iex(1)> Port.open({:spawn_executable, "/tmp/run.sh"}, [])
line 1             
      line 2                                                                                                   
            line 3                                                                                             
                  line 4
```

Comment: Found this very old thread with no solution posted: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-February/thread.html#49195

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the script under a wrapper that inserts a carriage return before the newline. Here's one such wrapper that uses `bash` and `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
"$@" 2>&1 | perl -pe 's/\n/\r\n/' 1>&2
```

Here's another using `bash` and `unix2dos`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
"$@" 2>&1 | unix2dos 1>&2
```

Basically, anything that can read the original program's `stderr`, replace newline with a carriage return and newline combination, and then write the result to `stderr` will work.

Put one of these solutions in a file named `/tmp/lf.sh`. Below we run it from iex with your original `/tmp/run.sh`, first with just the original script and then with the wrapper:

```
iex(1)> Port.open({:spawn_executable, "/tmp/run.sh"}, [])
#Port<0.5>
iex(2)> line 1
              line 2
                    line 3
                          line 4

nil
iex(3)> Port.open({:spawn_executable, "/tmp/lf.sh"}, [args: ["/tmp/run.sh"]])
#Port<0.6>
iex(4)> line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

nil
iex(5)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another quick and dirty solution (Elixir only)

```rb
Port.open({:spawn_executable, "/tmp/run.sh"}, [:use_stdio, :stderr_to_stdout, :binary, :hide]); receive do
  {_port, {:data, line}} -> String.split(line,"\n", trim: true) |> Enum.each(fn(x)-> IO.puts(x) end)
end
```

The question is what do you want to do with the data.

More info on link https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-802
quote:

```sh
elixir --no-halt -e ':user_drv.start();Port.open({:spawn, "bash -c '\''>&2 echo \"stderr\nline2\"'\''"}, [:binary])' 2> err.log
```

Comment: Thanks—my main issue is that I would like to keep stderr in stderr for logging purposes. Is there a way to capture stderr without joining it with stdout?